# Flow generics in react component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm trying to type a component's props with generics but flow doesn't catch the error. Basically, I want to have a component with two props `fetch` and `cb`. Whatever type `fetch` returns, should be the return type of `cb`.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';

type Props<T> = {
  fetch: () => Promise<T>,
  cb: T => T,
};

class Client<T> extends Component<Props<T>> {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetch, cb } = this.props;
    fetch().then(cb);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div />)
  }
}
        
const App = () => (
  <Client
    fetch={ () => Promise.resolve(1) } 
    cb={ n => 'sfd' } />
 );
```

At the bottom, I'm passing a function to `fetch` that resolves to `number` but the `cb` is returning a `string` and there is no flow error. Why?

Here is the [repl](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0A3qAMKwawB2hTeAvqJFg6AORYS5PgG5EiHAE90hUAAUe6AM4AeACoA+UAF5QVRKC6EcpABYAuUAAoAlDq0KGyJYXUaKB0KQBGltfdA1D3YxRFJoYiUlOmhkVhw3UEIADxxWABNo+kYWNhVHZTctfU9SBkxcnAARZHSAWVgAVzZbPU9DMqYlPBpIYzMKL29QTl0cU2cAOnRFJTFDQz6TU1tJ8dYrHxt5kfFDQSZ0wixW-QXQQRxGrCZrFXTkADdQYA0bT3ZET7DmbtAAQXQ6B0oBUtFi8Xa52hi36pm0NFa2gcPFQzkIk0ESlg0EehCsAEY7JwoTDzj4EaBbsj+EpIOk+CMXhoREA).

This is not even a `react` thing. A simple function will fail checking the type:

```
const fun = <T>(a: () => T, b: T => T): T => b(a());
fun(() => 2, n => 'qwe');
```

Comment: See [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0A3qAMKwawB2hTeAvqJFg6AORYS5PgG5EiHAE90hUAAUe6AM4AeACoA+UAF5QVRKC6EcpABYAuUAAoAlDq0KGyJYXUaKB0KQBGltfdA1D3YxRFJoYiUlOmhkVhw3UEIADxxWABNo+kYWNhVHZTctfU9SBkxcnAARZHSAWVgAVzZbPU9DMqYlPBpIYzMKL29QTl0cU2cAOnRFJTFDQz6TU1tJ8dYrHxt5kfFDQSZ0wixW-QXQQRxGrCZrFXTkADdQYA0bT3ZET7DmbtAAQXQ6B0oBUtFi8Xa52hi36pm0NFa2gcPFQzkIk0ESlg0EehCsAEY7JwoTDzj4EdYmJZulhkEwAOZ2ZH8JSQdJ8EYvDQiIA) it seems that flow needs a type of the `cb` argument

Comment: Just tacking onto Alex's comment: Flow seems to be inferring the type of the `cb` prop as `(string | number) => number`. That's why it "needs" the type specified for the cb arg.

Comment: Well, I use generics to avoid defining the concrete type :) and this is pretty basic type checking.

Answer (score 1):

In case of function you are wrong. It should be assign to a variable:

```
function f<T>(a: () => T, b: T => T): T {
    return b(a());
}

const r: number = f(() => 2, n => ""); // error
```

[try it](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQHwAoCGAuRLASkQF4NE0AaRAIwLTIrSIcQG8AoASACcBTKCF5JauYkQDcnAL6dECxQs4QEAZyiJeBMCAC2tfrzLIsxJogBMNJOUQAie1KA)

But in case of a component props... maybe it expect to be parameterized, but I can`t find a way to parameterize a component.

Comment: Tacking onto this, the reason you need to specify the `r: number` is that Flow thinks it's perfectly acceptable to return a `string | number` from your function. I'm not so sure that's the best interpretation to take, but that's the one it's taking.

Answer (score 1):

As James Kraus said on a comment, flow is inferring the type of your T to be
`number|string`. There is nothing preventing a generic to become a sum type, and unless you restrict one of the functions or parametrise your generic function with a concrete type, flow will continue to infer the sum type.

Very close to what Kirill wrote, but maybe easier to understand where the restriction is coming from is this:

```
function f<T>(a: () => T, b: T => T): T {
    return b(a());
}
        
const r = f<number>(() => 2, n => "");
```

Here you will get an error in the second function because we already told flow

> This generic must be a number, enforce it!

Then it does its job.